# Intersection of Three Spheres Gives Wrong Coordinates in ProGAL

Tags: java

I use [ProGAL](http://www.diku.dk/~rfonseca/ProGAL/) to find the two intersection points of three spheres.

Here is my code:

```
Point p0 = new Point(2,8,1);
Point p1 = new Point(5,9,17);
Point p2 = new Point(21,19,11);
Point p3 = new Point(7,4,1);
double r0 = p3.distance(p0);
double r1 = p3.distance(p1);
double r2 = p3.distance(p2);
Sphere s0 = new Sphere(p0, r0);
Sphere s1 = new Sphere(p1, r1);
Sphere s2 = new Sphere(p2, r2);
Point[] intersections = Sphere.getIntersections(s0, s1, s2);
for(Point point : intersections)
    System.out.println(point.x() + " " + point.y() + " " + point.z());
```

And this is the output:

```
8.748195083271948 1.1144249830330588 0.8525618604469422
-6.949424320444698 27.02495339639668 2.176457472808587
```

None of the points are even close to actual point `(7,4,1)`.

Is it because
i) Rounding errors?
ii) Wrong algorithm?
or
iii) Me doing something wrong?

Comment: Why the cgal tag? It doesn't look like progal is related.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I think they use PROGal to develop parts of their library.

Comment: What? No, CGAL doesn't use ProGAL in any way.

Comment: I meant the vice-versa. Sorry for my mistake. ProGAL uses CGAL, I mean.

Comment: Try squaring the radius [1](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Sphere__3.html#afaa9b613520cfde8fbd53c643c9cf921). Also look what kernel is used in this library.

Comment: @sloriot When I use squares of redii, the point array is empty.

Comment: Hi .. ProGAL developer here: It was a regular bug. I fixed it and uploaded a new jar. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @OnurÇağırıcı Oh .. and we don't have any dependency on CGAL in ProGAL. We use JAMA for the SVD and Eigen decompositions and Java3D for the visualization but other than that no dependencies.